# unable to put asp.net Table cell in web page

Tags: css, asp.net

Design problem. .......................................................................................................

I am struggling to put the "Primary Baseline Target" table cell properly. I tried various styles but it it didn't help. Thanks in advance.

Required:
[image]

My o/p:
[image]

css:

```
.labels {
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

Html

```
<fieldset style="border: solid; border-width: thin; width: 95%; height: 200px; border-color: #a8a8a8; margin: auto;">
    <legend id="Legend14" runat="server" visible="true" style="width: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #1f497d;">&nbsp;&nbsp; Project Performance &nbsp;&nbsp;</legend>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
        <asp:Table ID="table8" runat="server" CssClass="labels">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    Critical to Quality (CTQ)  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="590px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    Baseline Performance  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="590px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    Primary Metric  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="95px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    Primary Baseline Target  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="95px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    Secondary Metric  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="590px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    Target performance  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="590px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    Performance at Project Close  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="590px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to span the columns of the rows without two TextBoxes with `ColumnSpan`. Basically you need 4 columns, but those 4 are only required on rows 3 and 4. On all other rows you don't use them so you will have to span those starting at the second column.

```
<asp:Table ID="table8" runat="server" CssClass="labels">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Critical to Quality (CTQ)  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="590px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Baseline Performance  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell  ColumnSpan="3">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="590px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Primary Metric  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="95px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Primary Baseline Target  &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="95px" Height="23px" ></asp:TextBox> 
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```